# How Migrations are applied to the database?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I want to understand how migration works in entity framework, how ef knows which migration it should be applied to the database ?
I see that in every database there are a __MigrationHistory table that contains a list of migrations.

Does ef compare the migration in that table and the migration in the project before  applying a specific migration to the database ?

Comment: Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The history of applied migrations is listed in the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table. When EF compares the list of migrations in the code with the list of applied migrations in the database. Therefore, it tries to apply new migrations to the database in the order of their creation time.

Moreover, EF Core ignores items that are listed in the database and removed from the code.

By keeping the migrations in your code you can undo the scheme step-by-step with the order that they have applied to the database and listed in the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table.

Comment: Moreover, EF Core ignores items that are listed in the database and removed from the code. can you explain it more ?

Comment: I mean if you deleted the applied migrations you won't face any problem because EF Core only tries to apply the migrations that exist in the code but are not applied to the database